# Problem with WAMP server and Drupal on eeePC

Tags: drupal, wamp, eeepc

I just installed WAMP on my new eeePC and I am trying to install Drupal, I unzipped the drupal file in the www directory and went to localhost/drupal-x.xx

I get the following error for a couple hundred lines :

Deprecated: Function ereg() is deprecated in C:\wamp\www\drupal-6.15\includes\file.inc on line 902

then the regular drupal install interface appears at the bottom of the page, I tryed to go through with the installation but the problem remains, I looked through google and the drupal web site and I can find no answer (I found [similar problem (in french)](http://www.developpez.net/forums/d855271/webmasters-developpement-web/general-conception-web/debuter/install-drupal-6-15-message-derreur/), but no answer).

I have installed wamp and drupal on other computers (win XP and Mac OS) and it seems to work all right so it makes me think it might be related to the eeePC or windows 7 (running on windows 7 starter edition). Any idea ?

Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok it just seems that Drupal does not support PHP 5.3, which was installed in the latest version of WAMP, which I did not have on my other computers. I have to go back to 5.2, which you can do by installing a [php 5.2.x addon](http://www.wampserver.com/addons_php.php) from the wampserver website

If phpmyadmin doesn't work after installing your add, you will have to modify the php.ini file with the right path

> ; Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.
>
> extension_dir = "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.x.x/ext/"

replace php5.x.x by the version of php you downloaded and installed

My bad :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try with PHP 5.6 or PHP7 installtion,otherwise it will put depcrated notice on header area.